# How to implement the traditional imageView-inside-a-scrollView pan gesture with two fingers instead of one?

Tags: iphone, overriding, multi-touch, uigesturerecognizer, pan

I have an imageView nested inside of a scrollView that allows me to view an image, pinch to zoom, and pan around if I am zoomed in enough. Using a custom GestureRecognizer, I have (per the request of the person I'm building this app for) overridden the default behavior of the one finger pan so that it does something other than pan. This works perfectly.

Now the problem is that I still need the ability to pan around the image like I could with the one finger pan, I just need this to now be with two fingers. Is there a solution that can be implemented to utilize the already available features of the nested imageView? Or do I need to go through and after the two finger gesture is recognized, write my own custom pan-logic?

Any thoughts here are greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the UIPanGestureRecognizer class reference? There is a property in there minimumNumberOfTouches that can be set to enable a two finger pan gesture recognizer

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Capturing the event isn't what I am worried about as much as handling the results of the event. The nice thing about the default one finger pan with the nested imageView is that it's done all for you. I'm just hoping that I don't have to re-invent the wheel is all...

Comment: You can add a UIPanGestureRecognizer and then implement it something like this -  if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || 
  gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
  CGPoint translation;
  translation = [gesture translationInView:self];
  
  
  self.view.bounds.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.center.x + translation.x, self.view.bounds.center.y + translation.y);
  
  [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
 }

Comment: Perfect! Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Just not 100 percent sure if this coding is exact...it's close though. In the app I used this on, I implemented this in my custom view.

Comment: I had to take out the bounds part of the view because the center is accessible through the view, but other than that, it worked great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the newer versions if iOS you can merely adjust the parameters of the 'default' UIPanGenstureRecognizer that is already attached to the scrollView

```
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureObj in scrollView.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([gestureObj isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panObj = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureObj;
        panObj.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
        panObj.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    }
}
```

That should 'shift' the behavior to the 2 finger level

Comment: Just perfect. Saved a lot of time.