# Libgdx two-finger pan instead of single finger?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, gesture, pan

I've overridden the LibGdx  Pan gesture method for a different functionality (a selector). However, I want the pan functionality to use two fingers(pointers) instead. Is this possible?

It's the same question as this post, however his is specific to iPhone and not LibGdx:
[How to implement the traditional imageView-inside-a-scrollView pan gesture with two fingers instead of one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454546/how-to-implement-the-traditional-imageview-inside-a-scrollview-pan-gesture-with)

the pan() method will only fire with one finger, not two. I was thinking of keeping track of number of fingers used, by setting a variable in touchDown() using the int pointer  variable, however the pan() method will not fire when there are 2 fingers in use.

Any suggestions? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

After 3+ years of research I finally made it.

```
@Override
public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
    // Calculate distances
    float initialDistance = initialPointer1.dst(initialPointer2);
    float distance = pointer1.dst(pointer2);
    // Calculate pinch coordinates
    float initialPinchX = (initialPointer1.x + initialPointer2.x) / 2;
    float initialPinchY = (initialPointer1.y + initialPointer2.y) / 2;
    float pinchX = (pointer1.x + pointer2.x) / 2;
    float pinchY = (pointer1.y + pointer2.y) / 2;
    // This to avoid first time zooming or panning horrible behavior
    if (lastZoomDistance == 0) {
        lastZoomDistance = initialDistance;
    }
    if (lastPinchX == lastPinchY && lastPinchX == 0) {
        lastPinchX = initialPinchX;
        lastPinchY = initialPinchY;
    }
    // Zoom
    float distanceDifference = distance - lastZoomDistance;
    camera.zoom -= distanceDifference / 300;
    // Pan
    float deltaX = (pinchX - lastPinchX) * camera.zoom;
    float deltaY = (pinchY - lastPinchY) * camera.zoom;
    camera.translate(-deltaX, deltaY);
    // We need to update these for future calculations
    lastZoomDistance = distance;
    lastPinchX = (pointer1.x + pointer2.x) / 2;
    lastPinchY = (pointer1.y + pointer2.y) / 2;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to jig the `pinch()` method around to calculate a combined two finger panning and zooming gesture, instead of using `zoom()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code which achieves this using the `pinch` method, by looking at how far the first finger has been dragged from its initial position. The second finger is ignored.

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.GestureAdapter() {
    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
        float panAmount = pointer1.x - initialPointer1.x;
        // ...
        return true;
    }
})));
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto Luis' answe, sometimes you may want Pan/ Zoom to act as exclusive actions (only one can happen at a time). If that's what you're after, this may be useful

```
val targetVector1 = Vector2(pointer1).sub(initialPointer1)
val targetVector2 = Vector2(pointer2).sub(initialPointer2)

val isZoom = targetVector1.hasOppositeDirection(targetVector2)
val isPan = !isZoom
```